# HttpUrlConnection Java x Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have this code implemented in a normal java class and android..

```
public static String getURLPage(String urlString){
    URL url;
    String ret = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            ret += line;
        }
        reader.close();
        return ret;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

The code return the page correctly in Java, but in Android return error code 403...

I tried to set User-Agent, but nothing change..

What is the problem?

Comment: 403 means that the server refuses your repquest ('forbidden'). Have a look at the headers and check your server configuration if it doesn't allow certain headers.

Comment: Hint: You should use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) when you do a lot of concatenations on string (`ret` variable) as it's much faster than `String`.

Comment: HOw do i check allowed header if i don't have access to server configuration?

Answer (score -1):

//edit (sorry, I read over the 403 error first time)

detached from your problem with the 403 error, you can use the [Apache HTTP library](http://httpd.apache.org/), which is included in Android. You have nicer API than java.net.HttpURLConnection

Here is an example

```
    // imports from org.apache.http (http://hc.apache.org)
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

    int TIMEOUT = 2000;
    String url= "http://your-url.com;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    // which HTTP request: GET or POST ?
    //HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
    // example to show the result as a string
    String resultAsString= EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
```

This don't help directly, but bunting is right in his comment. You should look up the headers when it works (with java) and compare them when you using android.
The params you get with this command:

```
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
    // compare the headerParams
    Header[] requestHeader = get.getAllHeaders();
    Header[] responseHeader = rp.getAllHeaders();
```

Comment: Thios gives Erro Code 403... I set User-Agent = MOzilla still don't work

Comment: I edit my answer and tell you how you can look up the headers